# Is it safe to use internal storage as a "database"?

Tags: android, serialization, android-database

I have this little helper class:

```
public class InternalStorage {

private final static String fileName = "saves";

//Lista is átadható!
public static void writeObject(Context context, Object object, String key) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName + "_" + key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) {

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName + "_" + key);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object object = ois.readObject();
        return object;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

I use it to **save/load Serializable objects in my app.**

My question is that **is it safe to use this method with "important" data?**

I mean could the user **manipulate this data by modifying or deleting it accidentally or by purpose ?** Deleting app's cache or with any other tool?

Comment: What you're asking is a matter of opinion. Everyone has a different understanding of "important" and there are a lot of ways to solve the basic problem of data storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean could the user manipulate this data by modifying or deleting it accidentally or by purpose ?

Users can uninstall your app whenever they want. That will delete the data.

Users can clear data from your app whenever they want, via Settings. That too will delete the data.

Users who root their devices can examine your app's internal storage area and edit or delete whatever they want. This is a small percentage of Android users.

And, of course, there are extraordinary circumstances that might occur during the I/O (your app crashes, user force-stops your app or otherwise terminates your process, the battery runs out, the device gets stepped on by an elephant, etc.).

Outside of those scenarios, the user is unlikely to damage or delete the data, except as you permit through your app's UI.

> Deleting app's cache

This isn't cache, insofar as you are not using methods like `getCacheDir()` for this data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Let me ask you one more question, can other apps like memory cleaner apps delete these files?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: They should not be able to, except on rooted devices. I cannot rule out some security flaw that they might exploit. And if you put stuff in designated cache directories (`getCacheDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, etc.), those can be cleared by third-party apps with the right permission.